# How to get RETS data via http request

Tags: http, rets

Can any body tell me how to get data from RETS and store in Salesforce object. RETS 2 provide WSDL for SOAP 1.2 which salesforce can not convert to appropriate class and functions. So I have been trying using HTTP request from Salesforce. But I did not get any good document about accessing RETS data using http.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access RETS data through http easily.

I would recommend using a RETS client using the language of your choice, generate a database, then create an API that can do what you want.

http://wiki.rets.org/wiki/Opensource#Clients